# Proving $\frac{\cos(t \arctan(\sqrt{x}))}{(1+x)^{t/2}}= \sum_{k \ge 0}\frac{\Gamma(t+2k)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(t)\Gamma(2k+1)}\frac{(-x)^k}{k!}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, hypergeometric-function

$$\frac{\cos(t \arctan(\sqrt{x}))}{(1+x)^{t/2}}= \sum_{k \ge 0}\frac{\Gamma(t+2k)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(t)\Gamma(2k+1)}\frac{(-x)^k}{k!}$$
This is particularly nice, and apparently can be proved with the hypergeometric function, although solutions are by no means limited to this!

**Edit:** Random Variable's link below solves it using differential equations, but is there a more direct route via the hypergeometric function?

---

I've tried naively applying the Maclaurin series for $\cos, \arctan,(1+x)^{-n}$, but get such a mess where no discernible pattern emerges.

Comment: It is claimed in the following paper that both sides of the equation satisfy the same ordinary differential equation under the same initial conditions.  http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305131.pdf (Theorem 2.1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For simplicity, assume $x$ is real and positive.

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(t+2k)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(t)\Gamma(2k+1)}\frac{(-x)^k}{k!}
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(t)_{2k}}{2k!}(i\sqrt{x})^{2k}
= \Re\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(t)_k}{k!}(i\sqrt{x})^k\right)
= \Re\left(\frac{1}{(1-i\sqrt{x})^{t}}\right)
= \frac{1}{((1-i\sqrt{x})(1+i\sqrt{x}))^{t/2}}\Re\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt{x}}{1-i\sqrt{x}}\right)^{t/2}\\
= \frac{\Re\left(e^{it\arctan(\sqrt{x})}\right)}{(1+x)^{t/2}}
= \frac{\cos(t\arctan(\sqrt{x}))}{(1+x)^{t/2}}
$$